No electricity parachute deployment on egg drop
I am working on an egg drop project, and I have decided to use a design based on the Perseverance rover landing, but I need a parachute deployment system. My egg is dropping from about 11 feet and will reach a final velocity of about 8 m/s. I want to have the parachute deploy while the egg is going towards the ground without using any electrics, relying on external forces, and have the deployment mechanism be very light (at most a gram or two) and easy to make with craft materials.
If anyone can come up with a mechanism that would work, or ideas for a mechanism, that would answer my question.

Egg drop success is often determined by landing gear. Look into the ratio of the size of rover vs the altitude of the drop for some perspective. Detecting acceleration via springs and mass is feasible- target a force that does not apply (mostly) uniformly to all bodies

Thanks for your response! I'll look into what you're saying, but I was actually looking for more information about the deployment system for the parachute.

https://science.nasa.gov/resource/perseverance-deploys-its-parachute-illustration/ Altitude is commonly sensed via pressure sensors and radar (using electricity)

perhaps a light flexible film will deploy rapidly if shaped correctly, 11ft does not give much time...

I would be interested to see if ANY  parachute could slow the descent of an egg to non-breaking speed in 11 feet. A test would be to manually deploy a light flexible film parachute before and then drop the egg and see what happens.  If that works, you can pursue an automatic deployment system.

I think you are using "terminal velocity" incorrectly to mean final velocity. Dictionary definition is terminal velocity noun Physics:
the constant speed that a freely falling object eventually reaches when the resistance of the medium through which it is falling prevents further acceleration. You won't reach terminal velocity in ground-level atmosphere in 11 feet.

According to https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/free-fall, an 11' fall would take 820 ms. That seems very little to deploy a parachute, never mind decelerating the egg!

@Transistor My bad, kind of freestyled my question. Made edits!

The simplest solution would be a static line.
Would that be allowed under the rules of your competition?

When objects are in free-fall, they don't feel gravity.  Here's an idea, if you set up a weight that pushes down on a spring.  When in zero-G, the spring would push up the weight and something could happen to deploy your parachute or whatever.  This will be a royal pain to work with because if you don't keep it properly oriented, the parachute will deploy before dropping.  I did not say it was a good idea.
Part of the problem of slowing the fall with a parachute is it takes time for the parachute to fill with air to do any good slowing down the egg.  Can that happen fast enough?  I have no idea.
Another impractical idea is to replace the parachute with a balloon that is quickly inflated by opening a CO2 cartridge when zero G is detected.  Could the balloon be big enough, quickly enough?  Maybe, but it would be great fun trying to get it to work.
A more practical solution would be to have a big bag of popcorn and put the egg in the middle of that.  Another would be to suspend the egg in the middle of a box with rubber bands.  Those ideas would not be as much fun but they seem less likely to result in scrambled egg.

Food isn't allowed in my competion. Sorry, should have mentioned that!

I like your idea about the weight! I could align it with a PVC tube or something.
